# Historicity in Django

Tags: database, django, database-design, history

I want to create a couple of Object's in django model.
Such as Room[idRoom, nameRoom] and User[idUser, nameUser].

I want to have multiple Users in Room's and Room's for User.
I want to get all user's in specific Room and all Rooms by the User.

Also, I want to make History of changing for Room and User table.

Anybody can help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sketch of what you will need to have:

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Room(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="rooms")

class History(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# add some objects
first_user = User()
first_user.save()
first_room = Room()
first_room.save()
first_user.rooms.add(first_room)
History(room=first_room, user=first_user).save()
# ^^^ it automatically adds the current date and time

# now fetch them like this:
Room.objects.get(pk=the_room).users.all()
User.objects.get(pk=the_user).rooms.all()
User.objects.get(pk=the_user).history_set.order_by("-time")
```

Comment: Could you give an example with test data?